# VBA to Export Multiple Excel Sheets as one PDF File

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have several sheets that I want to export into one single PDF, while retaining the individual sheet numbering. I have looked at similar posts but am yet to get it working. The closest code that I have come across, which doesn't retain the individual sheet numbering (Sheet 1: Page 1 of 8..., Sheet 2: Page 1 of 2...) is this:

```
Public Sub Save_Sheets_As_PDF()

    Dim saveInFolder As String
    Dim replaceSelected As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim excludeSheets As String

    excludeSheets = "|abc|def|ghi|"        'The sheet names to exclude delimited by "|"

    saveInFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path
    If Right(saveInFolder, 1) <> "\" Then saveInFolder = saveInFolder & "\"

    With ThisWorkbook

        replaceSelected = True
        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            If InStr(excludeSheets, "|" & ws.Name & "|") = 0 Then
                ws.Select replaceSelected
                replaceSelected = False
            End If
        Next

        .ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=saveInFolder & "Sheets.pdf", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

        .Worksheets(1).Select True

    End With

End Sub
```

I am new to VBA, so my coding knowledge is a bit limited

Comment: There is no other way to export multiple sheets into one PDF than selecting them and run `ExportAsFixedFormat`. So you probably can only solve it by exporting them into single files each and use another tool to make one PDF file out of them.

Comment: @PEH That is what I am currently doing. Export individual PDFs then combine them. However, I was looking for a way to do all this in one simple step.

Comment: Well, I guess this is the only way to do it.